# Inverse match with java regex

Tags: java, regex, string-matching

My input strings are like this:

```
foo 12
12 foo 123
foo 12 foo 1234
f1o2o 12345
foo 12 123456
...
```

I need capture the last number: `12, 123, 1234, 12345, 123456 ...`
Every line is processed by separate:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*([0-9]+)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("foo 12 123456");
m.matches()
```

Output: `6`

Is there any form to inverse the matching? or how should I change the pattern for recover the last number?

Comment: make the .* lazy Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?([0-9]+)$");

Comment: Side note: in that particular case, you don't need a regex. Split the string by space and get the last element from the resulting array. (Works only in your specific case, with the sample data you provided)

Comment: why not just `split()` based on `\\s+` and get the last number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to group it simply check for digits followed by end of line.

```
\d+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rH1kI0/1)

sample code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+$",Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("foo 12 123456\n12 foo 123");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

output:

```
123456
123
```

---

Greedy looks for the matches as many times as possible, hence it capture digits as well and leave last digit for `[0-9]+`

Make it non-greedy as suggested by @Zack Newsham

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rH1kI0/6)

---

You can try with [Positive Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as well.

```
(?<=\D)\d+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rH1kI0/7)

Comment: +1 BTW group 1 will contain same match as group 0 so there is no real need to use `group(1)` over `group()`. Also in case if OP would have many lines in input you can use MULTILINE flag to let `$` match end of lines, rather than end of string.

Comment: Not sure what the exact requirements are, but if an input line can consist entirely of digits, the Positive Lookbehind won't work.

Comment: @ajb `I need capture the last number: 12, 123, 1234, 12345, 123456` does it make sense.

Comment: @ajb by the way there is no need for any extra pattern other than `(\d+)$`

Comment: I don't understand why you added anything beyond the first solution. Also unless java requires you to group, there'd be no need to group `\d+$` (though it may well be required by java, I have no idea)

Comment: @OGHaza yes there is no need to group. In that case use `Matcher#group()` as already suggested in the post.

Comment: I'm very confused by all these answers. Lots of very complex regex coming from knowledgeable users so I'll assume I'm missing something in the requirements, but otherwise [why not just this?](http://regexr.com/396ag)

Answer (score 1):

Change your greedy quantifier to a reluctant one and use a one-line approach:

```
String lastNum = str.replaceAll("^.*?(\\d+)\\D*$", "$1");
```

This extracts `123456` from `foo 12 123456` etc